# How to find sum of items inside of a tuple?

Tags: python, sqlite, sum, tuples, where-clause

Hello I want to be able to retreive a set of values from my SQLite database and add them all together. Then I want to insert this value into an antry widget on an app made with Tkinter. This is my code

```
 conn = sqlite3.connect('InvoiceHistory')
    D = conn.cursor()
    D.execute("""SELECT Invoice_Total FROM InvoiceHistory
               WHERE Cust_ID LIKE""" "'%" + Cust_ID_box.get() + "%'")
    All_Money = D.fetchall()
    Sum_Totals = sum(All_Money)
    VCB_Entry.insert(0,Sum_Totals)
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

when I use this code, I get this error:

```
  File "C:/Users/Lukas/Desktop/.idea/HatCo.py", line 967, in Show_Balance
    Sum_Totals = sum(All_Money)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'tuple'
```

I know the reason for this is because All_Money comes out like this when I print it to the console:

```
[(438.0,), (348.0,)]
```

My question is: How can I get these values out of a tuple and add them together? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a list comprehension to make a new list out of `All_Money` it would look something like this:

`sum([inner_tup[0] for inner_tup in All_Money])`

and will produce something like:

`sum([438.0, 348.0])`

which is acceptable input for the sum method

Comment: Another good option if the tuples may contain more than one value could be: `sum([sum(inner_tup) for inner_tup in All_Money])`

Comment: Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!!

Comment: @LukasOrozco If this answer has solved your problem you should accept it, so other can find it more easily and it can help more people how are facing the same issue.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply to the computation in the database? This is simpler and more efficient:

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('InvoiceHistory')
cur = conn.cursor()
cust_id = "%" + Cust_ID_box.get() + "%"
cur.execute("SELECT SUM(Invoice_Total) FROM InvoiceHistory WHERE Cust_ID LIKE ?" , (cust_id, ));
rec = cur.fetchone()
sum_totals = rec[0]
```

Note that I changed your code to pass the variable as a query parameter rather than concatenating it into the query string: parameterized queries make your code safer (when the input comes from outside the program), and more efficient (the database does not need to re-parse the query each time it is executed).